# Can't open Play Store web Intent after using Cordova cli-6.0.0

Tags: cordova

Google gave me a security error about my app. It shows that Apache Cordova has some security vulnerabilities. I tried upgrading it to Cordova `cli-6.0.0`. I am building my app with PhoneGap.

After reading about whitelisting issues in cordova-whitelist-plugin I added `<allow-intent>` and `<allow-naviation>` preferences in the PhoneGap xml config file.

After upgrading, all my Play Store urls stopped working.
Here is my config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.example.example"
        version   = "1.0.6">

    <name>Statistical quality control</name>

    <description>
        description about app
    </description>

    <author href="http://apps.example.com" email="support@example.com">
        authorname
    </author>
    <preference name="LoadingDialog" value="Application Warming Up..."/>
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>
    <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-6.0.0' />
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="11" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="internalOnly" />

     <gap:platform name="android" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.3" />
      <icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
    <access origin="*" browserOnly="true"/>
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Can take the security error you are currently seeing and add it to the question please?

Comment: here is full error ,** Security alert
Your app is using a version of Apache Cordova containing one or more security vulnerabilities. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the app.**
And here is a link which explain everything about error, https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6325474